# Send image from android to php webservice JSON

Tags: php, android, json, web-services

I'm trying to send a image from my android app to the php webservice, so it can be saved at my server and show in a web system that I have. The problem is, I'm not been able to decode in PHP. I checked, and the encoded string is been send from android to php webservice with no problem, but the image is not been converted, the data is been saved at the database, but not the image, I checked and the variable that I used to save the image decoded is null.

Here is my code that convert the image in java:

```
final Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile( tempFotoPropriedade.getNomeArquivo() );

ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

bitmap.compress( Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 50, stream );

byte [] byte_arr = stream.toByteArray();

String imageString = Base64.encodeToString( byte_arr, Base64.DEFAULT );
```

Here is my code in php to decode de string recived(the string is been reviced):

```
$binary = base64_decode( $foto["nomearquivo"] );
```

$binary is null, but $foto["nomearquivo"] has the string byte.

What should I do? I'm not been able to save the image because of that.

Comment: you sure it's null? boolean false, maybe? that'd indicate b64_decode failed, and whatever you passed in isn't base64

Comment: I passed as a response in my json, and printed in java log, it was "null". So it is null? Right?

Comment: `var_dump($binary)` will tell you what it is. if it's a real php null, then you get `NULL`. if it's the STRING 'null', you'd get `string(4) = "null"`, etc...

Comment: I did it: $response["binary"] = $binary; echo json_encode($response);

Comment: I also did the same with the $foto["nomearquivo"] and returned me a huge string.